US ESTA Overstay dilemma
Just left the USA and then had a flurry of emails saying I had overstayed by 16 days, now have my ESTA in pending status and Global Entry has been rescinded.  My I-94 has the correct travel details for me and shows I was in country for 82 days on my departure, always very careful to ensure I do not get too near the limit.  No idea why I am being flagged as overstaying.  Have filed the paperwork to challenge the overstay but concerned this will take an age.  Any advice on how to resolve this as quickly as possible?  Cannot find any info for a correct I-94 but overstay violation issue.

What "paperwork" did you file?

From whom did you get the emails?

Did you check https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/home ? Any anomaly or missing exit there?

Emails all genuine CBP and have spoken to them to confirm details. All I94 details correct and confirms my 82 day duration of stay.

I'm not sure I follow. You're saying that CBP tells you you overstayed, while also CBP tells you you didn't? How does that work? It seems that something is missing in the story - were you granted entry for less than the 82 days you've stayed?

I stayed 82 days - my I94 confirms this. Yet still had an overstay violation according to the email and CBP response. No other info available and definitely no restriction on my 90 day duration for the ESTA!

I understand that you've stayed 82 days. How many days were you granted?

The I-94 site should show and "Arrival/Issued Date:" and an "Admit Until Date:", though I'm not sure this is still visible once you have exited. If they are still shown, what do they say? Also, did you by any chance stay in the US, travel to Mexico, Canada, or nearby islands, then come back to the US? More generally, what's your I-94 history (arrival/departure dates) for the last year?

Also, did you use contact info found independently, or included in the e-mail to talk to them? What did they say? What paperwork did you submit, and how?

Where do you live?  Did you travel from the US to Canada, Mexico, or the Caribbean and then back to the US?

just because you stayed less than 90 days doesn't mean you didn't overstay your ESTA. E.g. you could have left the US AFTER the end date of the ESTA, or in theory entered before its start date.

@jwenting ESTA has to be valid on entry. It doesn't matter if it's validity expires while in the USA. You probably can't enter before it's start date; the air carrier should not let you board the aircraft without a valid ESTA.

ESTA was in date and valid for the 2 yr period, stay was 82 days.  All of my stay was in the US with no external travel.  Contact with CBP has been through their website not via email links to ensure it was not phishing.  Paperwork submitted was a reply email to CBP where they asked for documentation to confirm length of stay (air tickets, I94 proof etc).  Last entry to the US was spring this year, under 90 day stay and departed in early May.

@Timmo I think the question still remains regarding how long you were admitted for. Yes ESTA allows for up to 90 days, but it's up to the CBP officer to decide your length of stay. When is your "admit until date" in the online i94? Is the total permitted stay less than 90 days?

Yes - agree. I can’t see any comments on a stay restriction on my (post departure I94). This is the first time I have heard of an I94 as had always taken my stay length to be a standard 90 days. Not sure how you are expected to track this without being made fully aware of how to confirm any changes from the normal ESTA stay expectation.

@vidarlo I think the real reason you can't enter before your ESTA start date is that they are always valid from the moment of issue.  (The same is true of US visas, which do not have a "start date" but only an issue date.)

@Ozzy the visa waiver program regulations do not give CBP officers any discretion to admit travelers for a shorter period than 90 days unless they are returning from contiguous territory or adjacent islands, and even then the discretion is only to choose between admitting them for a new 90-day period or to resume an existing 90-day period from their prior VWP admission.

@phoog thanks for the comment. Didn't think the US gave their officers any restrictions on their power to decide admission length (besides a supervisor override being needed).
